# Able to sign-in any user in gerrit

Tags: gerrit

Why am I able to switch to any user from the web UI. I have attached the screenshot below. If I click on admin or gerrit_user1 from any of the systems in the network I am able to login as that user.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Gerrit server is configured as "DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT". There's the following configuration in the GERRIT-SITE/etc/gerrit.config file:

```
[auth]
    type = DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT
```

When this is the configured authentication method, you can enter the username of any existing user account, and immediately login as that account, without any authentication taking place. This isn't the usual way to work with Gerrit.

See more info at Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#auth).